# Duplicate icons of an application, running in Wine

Tags: wine, launcher, .desktop

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 and Docky as my launcher. To run `OriginPro` under `Wine` from launcher I created a `.desktop` file and pinned it to my Docky

However, when it starts, it opens a separate icon (which I can't pin to Docky by right-click). I had a similar problem with Matlab (not wine), but changing the `.desktop` file's name to exactly match the one that opens when I click on it made them group, but it doesn't work for `OriginPro`.

Comment: No. When it's loading it has a Wine logo, after that it changed to the correct one. http://i.imgur.com/tfGj40z.png

Comment: I see, see my answer, I mention Unity, but it makes no difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens (not only) with Wine applications. I assume your application does not have a *duplicated* launcher, since you cannot pin it to the Unity Launcher (or Docky in your case). The second icon will most likely be a generic one, or a "general" `Wine` icon.

The second icon appears because the launcher and the application window do not "meet" each other.

#### What to do

1. Open `OriginPro`
2. Open a terminal, type the command `xprop WM_CLASS` + <kbd>return</kbd>, the cursor will change into a big `+`.
3. Click on the window of `OriginPro`, in the terminal you will find an output like:

   ```
   WM_CLASS(STRING) = "finale.exe", "Wine"
   ```

   (In the example of `Finale`, your output will be different)
4. Open your `.desktop` file, add a line, starting with `StartupWMClass=`, + the section of the output, identifying your application, like (again the `Finale` example):

   ```
   StartupWMClass=finale.exe
   ```

Now your application launcher is "connected" to the application:

[image]

Comment: This is a wonderful tip!  Thanks for showing me how to do this as well :)

Comment: I wonder why this is not done automatically. In Unity I never had this problem.